# Software and hardware requirements of WebGL on Windows

Tags: javascript, windows, electron, webgl, chromium

I'm creating a desktop-only Windows application and will use Electron, which uses Chromium. Chromium supports WebGL 2. I've read that WebGL on Windows is translated to DirectX calls by the ANGLE library (so OpenGL is not used at all).

Is it true that on each GPU where WebGL 1 runs, then WebGL 2 will run too? What's the required DirectX version for WebGL 1 and WebGL 2?

Comment: No, you can see [here](https://webglstats.com/) that WebGL2 support is much less than WebGL1 support

Comment: Yes, I saw that before, but these statistics include different browsers, right? So IE, Edge, Safari and others will decrease percentage. I'm interested only in Chrome on WIndows (sorry, I didn't mentioned WIndows in my question).

Comment: You can drill down to [just Chrome on Windows on that site](https://webglstats.com/webgl2?platforms=000002000000000000). IIRC WebGL2 support in Electron requires at least DirectX 11 support at some certain version. Also, at least in Chromium there is a blacklist of drivers that are known to have bugs. You can turn off that blacklist in Electron and it will be up to you to workaround whatever bugs you find.

Comment: @gman Oh, I didn't noticed the filtering option, it's very useful, thank you! Do you also know if the blacklist is the same for WebGL2, or there is a separate blacklist maybe?

Answer (score 0):

of course not. each version requires different extension impl on GPU, need to be checked separately. for example try http://webglreport.com/ what ext for each version requires.

Answer (score -1):

No, Your hardware/drivers needs to support the appropriate opengl version:

- WebGL 1.0 exposes the OpenGL ES 2.0 feature set;
- WebGL 2.0 exposes the OpenGL ES 3.0 API.

[source](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/)

So if your hardware only supports OpenGL ES 2.0, webgl2 won't run.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mentioned in my question that I'm asking about Windows specifically. I've read that on Windows all WebGL calls are converted to DirectX calls by ANGLE, so OpenGL is not used at all. I'm bit confused by that.

Comment: @HankMoody thats true, on windows you don't need any OpenGL support and for the record on desktop mac and linux you don't need any OpenGL *ES* support either, native OpenGL *ES* is only used on mobile devices.